# Laravel - Unable to Migrate table with both 1:N and 1:1 Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I have the following Migration tables:

```
class CreateQuizzesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('quizzes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('set null');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('quizzes');
    }
}
```

And

```
class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('quiz_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->foreign('quiz_id')->references('id')->on('quizzes')->onDelete('set null');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
    }
}
```

A customer can create (and thus has) multiple quizzes (1:N). The reason why the **customers** table has a **quiz_id** field is that, of those he has created, only one can be active at a time (1:1).

The problem is that it crashes when I try to migrate, since both tables reference eachother, notifying me that the other table doesn't exist yet.

If I set **CreateQuizzesTable** to execute first:

> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation does not exist «customers»

If I set **CreateCustomersTable** to execute first:

> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation does not exist «quizzes»

I insist, this is not an N:M relationship, I would like to avoid intermediate tables to manage this.

UPDATE: after checking out @JasperStaats answer, I still have issues with the seeding of the tables. Since one of the two table seeders has to be executed first, it expects the foreign key value of the other table to already exist in the DB (e.g.: if I execute QuizzesTableSeeder first, it will be unable to insert the value 'customer_id' => 1 since the customers table is still empty. For now, I leave that field value null and then go to the DB and replace it with appropiate value, but this is not ideal.

Seed Execution Order File:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(QuizzesTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(CustomersTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Customer seeder file:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CustomersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        \DB::table('customers')->delete();

        \DB::table('customers')->insert(array(
            0 =>
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'quiz_id' => 1,
                'name' => 'user1',
                'password' => 'pass1'
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Quiz seeder file:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class QuizzesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        \DB::table('quizzes')->delete();

        \DB::table('quizzes')->insert(array(
            0 =>
            array(
                'id' => 1,
                'customer_id' => 1,
                'name' => 'quizz1',
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe the problem is in your sequence of migration files..

Comment: A solution you can make is, creating the table first without that relation (or only unsigned if it works) and then a migration to sign that key to the other table. Never had this problem so I don't know if it's the best solution.

Comment: may be you need to create first customer table then only you can refer it in quizzes table. so just try it first create customer table and then create quizzes table.

Comment: @sandy I already explained in my question that the order of execution/creation doesn't matter since both tables reference eachother with FKs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend to migrate first the tables and then make a new migration that makes the foreign keys.

```
php artisan make:migration add_foreign_keys
```

Then

```
class AddForeignKeysTable extends Migration
    {
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::table('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {

                $table->foreign('quiz_id')->references('id')->on('quizzes')->onDelete('set null');
            });

            Schema::table('quizzes', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers')->onDelete('set null');
            });


        }

        public function down()
        {
            Schema::table('customers',function(Blueprint $table){
                // Place foreign key name
                $table->dropForeign('FOREIGN_KEY_NAME');
            });

            Schema::table('quizzes',function(Blueprint $table){
                // Place foreign key name
                $table->dropForeign('FOREIGN_KEY_NAME');
            });
        }
    }
```

This way you are sure the foreign keys will be added if the tables exist

Comment: It works, I will give it as valid if no better answer arises in the next hours :) Do you happen to know a similar trick for the database seeding part? I have the same problem there

Comment: Could you post an example of that? Because I have no idea what you are doing atm with the seeding.

Comment: I have updated my question explaining the seeding part